# How can I multiple Strings with Integers in Javascript as in python, if we cant what's the reason and is there any other way to do so?

Tags: javascript, python

```
#Python Code
characters = "Hello World!"
print(characters * 4)  #it Will Print Hello World! 4 times

// Javascript Code
characters = "Hello World!"
console.log(characters * 4)
```

Comment: I don't know the reasoning why Python *would* allow this, but I'm not familiar with much of the philosophy of Python.  In JavaScript this "doesn't work" simply because performing math on text makes no sense.

Comment: @David please, let's not start discuss JavaScript and "makes sense" :) Anyway, you can't argue that `string * 4` does not work in JS because "performing math on text makes no sense" while JS allows `string + 4` (which Python does **not** allow, BTW). It just that `*` is not **defined** in JS for string and integer operands, not that "it makes no sense"

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use the inbuilt property 'repeat' of a string

```js
characters = "Hello World!";
console.log(characters.repeat(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repeat()`.

```
const chorus = 'Hello World! ';
console.log(`${chorus.repeat(4)}`);
```

Edit: Use the other person's reply instead of mine, it's way simpler